Coefficient in Regression Analysis
I am running regression on two variables (independent and dependent).
If the results show p-value > 0.05, it is not statistically significant. Does this mean we reject the coefficient as well? If the coefficient is negative, can we at least say the relationship is negative?

While you shouldn't rely solely on p-values when making inferences, if you did set out to test your hypothesis with p-values, and your p-value is larger than your critical value, then that means you don't have sufficient evidence to say that your regression coefficient is different from zero. So no, you shouldn't say your regression coefficient is negative. A good practice is to compute and report confidence intervals for the coefficient. If you do that you'll probably see that they contain zero (e.g. range from -.10 to .08), which illustrates why you shouldn't say the coefficient is positive or negative.
You can also try to understand why the coefficient is non-significant. Have you plotted the raw data? Maybe the relationship is not linear. What size is the coefficient, and what size is its standard error? Is the coefficient very small, or is it substantial but also has large error? Could your sample size be relevant?
What you should do depends heavily on your research context, but if you are doing inference, you don't have to "reject" the coefficient, you can report that there was no evidence for a relationship between your variables, and interpret this lack of evidence.
